# Does anyone know of any attempt to implement the Web Sockets API using libevent in C/C++?

Tags: c++, websocket, asyncsocket

I need opensource Web Sockets API using libevent in C/C++. Please show me where to find it.

Comment: Have you looked at this?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_WebSocket_implementations

Comment: Do you just need a c++ Web Sockets server - why does it have to use libevent?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [evws](https://github.com/Aulos/evws) or [libwebsock](https://github.com/payden/libwebsock) which is based on libevent. I haven't used it yet for myself but it looks quite promising.

If it doesn't match your requirements you could build something yourself (probably based on [libevtp](https://github.com/ellzey/libevhtp) which provides an improved HTTP API for libevent). See [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) for the protocol specification.